# ROS users migrated to Robotics Stack Exchange – how to link accounts?

Tags: support, ros-migration, user-accounts

I do have an account in [ROS Answers](https://answers.ros.org/questions/) with the same nickname. I see my questions in ROS Answers have been moved here.

However, the migrated account holding my nickname is not linked to mine in here. Would there be a policy that regulates this issue?

[This is my post from ROS Answers that has been moved to our beloved Robotics community.](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/add-message-files-directory-not-found)

---

Update:

I've tried to contact the support team via Contact Support but since the second account is greyed out, I get this error

```
We can't merge until we have links to both profiles; please add the missing URL and try again.
```

Answer (score 4):

When we did the migration, we put a call out for all users to provide us with user IDs on each site for doing the remapping during the migration.

For example: https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-and-gazebo-answers-migration-to-robotics-stack-exchange-process/31494

> Please fill out https://forms.gle/uRnWUC2taNVij2nw9 33 to let us know how to associate your answers.ros.org and answers.gazebosim.org accounts to your Robotics.SE account
> You won’t earn reputation for the votes in ROS or Gazebo Answers, but you will when people upvote migrated questions hosted on Robotics.SE after the migration.

And repeated and pinned: https://discourse.ros.org/t/important-final-ros-gazebo-answers-migration-schedule/32779

However, it looks like [there's an official process for merging accounts](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). However, I'm not sure if there's unique account information retained in the import process, as the username associated with your imported account doesn't appear to have a profile linked to be able to do that account merge capability.

**Edit: Update**

I got a chance to talk to a CM. Unfortunately because there's no way to now authenticate the users profiles after the migration the Stack Exchange team has no secure way to verify that the accounts are coowned and as such they cannot connect the accounts anymore. I'm sorry to those who didn't see the message in the months when we were advertising it and promoting it, but at this point the migration is complete and we can't reprocess it.

Comment: I've probably missed your announcements. We are no longer able to access the form. What can we do now to resolve this issue?

Comment: Since the migration has been completed please try reaching out to support as linked above about merging accounts. I don't know if there's enough metadata retained to do that, but hope that there is. Without the additional profile link you'll have to open a general purpose support issue.

Comment: Unfortunately the process to merge accounts doesn't work if the second account is on ros answers. And you can't send the form without a second account url.  I get following message: " We can't merge until we have links to both profiles; please add the missing URL and try again "

Comment: @Tully *"we put a call out for all users to provide us with user IDs on each site"*, **we didn't see it**, and **no notification via email** was sent to ROS answers users!

Comment: @Tully "*there's no way to now authenticate the users profiles after the migration*", there should be a way, I still can access my account in ROS Answers: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCGqq.png) and I have the right to claim my ownership of my Q&A: [e.g:](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/102390/gazebo-for-testing-offline-with-the-new-abb-robot-driver)