# Account migration from ROS answers to Robotics SE

Tags: discussion

I am aware of the transition to use Robotics Stack Exchange from ROS Answers. I followed this post "[Call for Action: ROS Answers Migration Account Association](https://discourse.ros.org/t/call-for-action-ros-answers-migration-account-association/32037/1)" after reading "[ROS and Gazebo Answers Migration to Robotics Stack Exchange Process](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-and-gazebo-answers-migration-to-robotics-stack-exchange-process/31494)". I have a ROS Answers account where I made multiple contributions and also learned; I wanted to migrate this account to Robotics SE but the google form link has expired. I am unable to see the questions which I asked and answered on Robotics SE. What are steps I can take now to facilitate the migration of my account to Robotics SE?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen several people be pointed at this [ROS users migrated to Robotics Stack Exchange – how to link accounts?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/ros-users-migrated-to-robotics-stack-exchange-how-to-link-accounts) as an "official answer" - although I am not sure if it actually works.